# Image resizing, maintaing image size - beginner question

Tags: image, image-processing, imagemagick, gimp

Im attempting to resize an image from 480x800 to 320x240. Below are the results. The original image has an oval shaped circle whereas the resized image has a more spherical shape. Is it possible to resize the original image so that the circle and rectangle are in their original proportions but smaller?

Can imagemagick or gimp (or other software) achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Imagemagick solution.

1) If you want large image to just fit 320x240 box and leave proportions, use:

```
convert test.png -size 320x240 resized.png
```

That will produce image sized 144x240.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#resize

2) If you want large image to completely fill a specific image size, use:

```
convert test.png -resize 320x240\> \
    -size 320x240 xc:blue +swap -gravity center -composite \
    resized.jpg
```

That will produce image sized 320x240 with resized big image in center and blue fill on sides.

http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#space_fill